# Error opening programatically created .docx file

Tags: document-library, word

I am getting an error while pragmatically creating .docx file from template. Here is my code:

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string TemplateUrl = string.Empty;
                        try
                        {
                            TemplateUrl = url + "/Projects/Forms/template.dotx";
                        }
                        catch { }


                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList olist = web.Lists["Projects"];
                        SPFolder newfolder = olist.RootFolder;
                        SPFile file = null;
                        SPContentTypeCollection currentOrder = olist.ContentTypes;
                        List<SPContentType> result = new List<SPContentType>();
                            foreach (SPContentType ct in currentOrder)
                            {
                                if (ct.Name.Contains("Document"))
                                {
                                    result.Add(ct);
                                }
                            } 

                            file = web.GetFile(TemplateUrl);

                            if (file != null)
                            {
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                     Stream readStream =         file.OpenBinaryStream(SPOpenBinaryOptions.None); //file is SPFile type
                                SPFile uploadedFile = newfolder.Files.Add(newfolder.Url + @"/" + prjName + ".docx", readStream, true);
                                uploadedFile.CheckOut();
                                SPListItem listitem = uploadedFile.Item;
                                listitem["Title"] = prjName;
                                listitem["Team_x0020_Members"] = fv1;
                                listitem.Update();
                                uploadedFile.Update();
                                uploadedFile.CheckIn(string.Empty);
                                olist.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = result;
                                olist.RootFolder.Update(); 
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                            }
                    }
                }
            });
```

And here's the error I get when opening the new Word document:
[image]

Comment: What's the size of the new file, as reported by SharePoint when you display the file properties?

Comment: as of now there is no content i have written in the file. As i want blank file to be created. The blank file size  is 22.0 KB

Comment: Document is getting uploaded properly. but when i download from the library and try to open it i am getting an error

Comment: I understand you want the new file to be a blank one, copied from Template.dotx. But can you check the size of the new file? My assumption is it's 0-byte, thus the error when you open it Word.

Comment: Yes its 22 KB not 0 byte. And if your assumption is such then can you tell me how to add some content into the file so that it can open properly. As i don't have knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the content type as "Document" in your code . File created through the code does not inherit the content type required for a file .

Comment: I have updated my code as above. but no effect. still the same error